# How can we prove that the internal angle bisector and external angle bisector of a triangle are in Harmonic progression (H.P.).

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> The internal angle bisector and external angle bisector of a triangle
> are in Harmonic progression (H.P.).

I think this is a theorem but I haven't found any proof of this theorem. I am trying to solve it but I can not please help me!
Refer to this image:

[image: Refer to this image.]

Here we have to prove $BD$, $BC$ and $BD'$ are in Harmonic Progression. According to this theorem then $D$ and $D'$ are Harmonic conjugates of each other which implies that $BD:DC$ is same as $BD':CD'$.
So basically we have to prove that the ratios are same which proves that $D$ and $D'$ are harmonic conjugates and $BD$, $BC$ and $BD'$ are in H.P.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a [tour]. since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: What, exactly, is in a Harmonic progression? Are the measures of the three divisions (BS, SC, CS') in this order?

Comment: @Feripinho please see the necessary edits I have made for the better understanding of the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you edit. I'm going to refer to the figure you made.

Let $\overline{AB} = b$, $\overline{AC} = c$ and $\overline{BC} = a$.

Since $\overline{AD}$ is an internal bisector, $\dfrac{\overline{BD}}{b} = \dfrac{\overline{DC}}{c} \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DC}} = \dfrac{b}{c}$.

Since $\overline{AD'}$ is an external bisector, $\dfrac{\overline{BD'}}{b} = \dfrac{\overline{CD'}}{c} \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{\overline{BD'}}{\overline{CD'}} = \dfrac{b}{c} =\dfrac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DC}}$, proving your statement.

It's also possible to actually calculate $\overline{BD}$ and $\overline{BD'}$:

$\dfrac{\overline{BD}}{b} = \dfrac{\overline{DC}}{c} = \dfrac{\overline{BD}+\overline{CD}}{b+c} = \dfrac{a}{b+c} \therefore \overline{BD} = \dfrac{ab}{b+c}$. Doing the same to $\overline{BD'}$, we get $\overline{BD'} = \dfrac{ab}{b-c}$.

$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{\overline{BD}} + \dfrac{1}{\overline{BD'}} =\dfrac{b+c}{ab} + \dfrac{b-c}{ab} = \dfrac{2b}{ab} = 2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right) = 2\left(\dfrac{1}{\overline{BC}}\right)$, meaning $\overline{BD}$, $\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{BD'}$ are in harmonic progression.

Comment: I understand it now, I was a little confused btw I have another solution we use sine of angle AD'B to prove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#Theorem) and the [exterior angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#Exterior_angle_bisectors):
$$
BD:DC=AB:AC=BD':CD'.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This question is about the harmonic range cut off by the
extended two side lines of an angle of a triangle and its
internal and external angle bisectors as in the web page
[Properties of the Harmonic Ratio](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/HarmonicRatioProperties.shtml) at
`www.cut-the-knot.org` which uses circles of Apollonius.

This is an application of a known theorem on
[Projective harmonic conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate).
The Wikipedia article states

> The four points are sometimes called a harmonic range (on the real projective line) as it is found that D always divides the segment AB internally in the same proportion as C divides AB externally.

This concept is a projective invariant. Thus, it is
enough to prove it for an isosceles triangle where
the two sides $AB$ and $AC$ are equal. In this case,
$D$ is the midpoint of side $BC$ and $D'$ goes to
infinity. In terms of coordinates on the line $BDCD'$,
the quadruple of $(0, 1/2, 1, \infty)$ form a harmonic
range since the lengths $(1/2, 1, \infty)$ are
in harmonic progression.

In more detail, the cross-ratio of the pair $(D,D')$
relative to $(B,C)$ is defined a the quotient of external
and internal division ratios $BD'/CD'$ by $BD/CD$. This is
a projective invariant. Thus, if the four lines through
the point $A$ are cut by another line to give new points
$\hat{B},\hat{D},\hat{C}$ such that $A\hat{B}$ and
$A\hat{C}$ are equal, then this other triangle $A\hat{B}\hat{C}$
is isosceles. This implies line segments $\hat{B}\hat{D}$ and
$\hat{D}\hat{C}$ are congruent. Note that here the external
bisector at point $A$ is now parallel to line $\hat{B}\hat{C}$.